# keep receiving - SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, runtime-error

My Code Runs When I Test It Within The Program, But When I Try To run Rspec on The Code It Throws a Error

```
rails--version
Rails 5.2.3

ruby --version
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x64-mingw32]
```

I have Tried Making The Variables Public And Also Removing Variables and writing the code in different ways

Test File

```
require 'sort'
describe Sorter do
    let (:sort) { Sorter.new }
    let (:array) {array[10,6,2,1,5,4,3,9,8,7]}
    context "Sort Low To High" do
        it "Goes From 1 - 10" do
            expect(sort.sortup(array)).to eql([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
        end
    end
    context "Sort High To Low" do
         it "Goes From 10 - 1" do
            expect(sort.sortdown(array)).to eql([10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
        end
    end
end
```

Main File

```
class Sorter
    def sortup array
        j = 0
        while j < array.length - 1
            i = 0; 
            while i < array.length - 1
                if(array[i] > array[i+1])
                    temp = array[i+1]
                    array[i+1] = array[i]
                    array[i] = temp
                end
                i += 1
            end
            j += 1
        end
        array
    end
end
```

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace

     SystemStackError:
       stack level too deep
```

Comment: `let (:array) {array[10,6,2,1,5,4,3,9,8,7]}` the defintion of `array` keeps calling itself. change this to `let (:array) {[10,6,2,1,5,4,3,9,8,7]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> let (:array) {array[10,6,2,1,5,4,3,9,8,7]}
> ```

The way `let` works is that essentially it defines a method whose name is the `Symbol` you pass to `let` and the body is the block. So, this is essentially equivalent to

```
def array
  array[10,6,2,1,5,4,3,9,8,7]
end
```

As you can see, `array` calls itself, and there is no condition for it to stop doing so, so you get endless recursion. The solution is simple: don't have it call itself.

It is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve with this call, so I can't give better advice, unfortunately.